# Getting error while deploying code to production-->Previous load of class failed: qbdialer|insidesalessetup

Tags: deployment, package, salesforce

I am facing an error conflict while deploying any code to the production.
Error is:

```
    Previous load of class failed: qbdialer|insidesalessetup
```

qbDialer is a managed package.

Can anybody please help me to overcome from this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your insidesalessetup class trying to call a method somewhere within qbdialers package? These errors tend to indicate you have a pre-existing class which has a reference to a method or class that no longer exists.

For example, if I created a class with a method Add(integer x, integer y, integer z), wrote a test method that called Add(1,2,3), then saved these they would both save okay. If I altered the method to just be Add(integer x, integer y) - removing the z parameter - I would get the error you are on about when I next ran my tests.

Paul